# JavaScript - Get and display current time in <input type="time">

Tags: javascript, html

How do I display the current time in an `input` whose `type` is `time` and hide its picker icon?

Thank you all.

Comment: sure, but it depends what you mean by current. Current time at the time when the page loads? or a running current time, which updates every second (or minute) while the page is open ?

Comment: running current time which updates every second while the page is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the input's `valueAsDate` property to the current date.

You can use the `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` pseudo-class to select the picker icon.

```js
input.valueAsDate = new Date()
```

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="input">
```

Comment: but what if i am working with two input types (e.g. input type="datetime-local" and input type="time")

Comment: @s.alonzo I would suggest you ask another question.